# nginx proxy, wget, and lynx all fail but openssl s_client and curl both work

Tags: nginx, ssl, openssl

I'm trying to create a proxy in nginx and I'm having a weird problem.  I'm trying to create an NGINX proxy that just works and ignores every cert problem, cert issue, cert thingy imaginable.  I just want it to proxy the traffic regardless of how bad the cert is (and I know it's pretty bad!)

It's a pretty simply nginx config and if I try it against https://www.google.com I can proxy without any issue.  If I try it against my real site I get a time out error.  The site also won't load in lynx or wget no matter what options I feed them to ignore cert errors.

The interesting thing is that the site loads fine in any typical browser and I've tested wtih IE, Chrome, and firefox.  The site also loads fine in openssl s_client and with curl.  But nginx, lynx, and wget all think they're getting incomplete data and either time or or give errors like "No Data Recieved."

Since NGINX is what I really want to get working, here's my config:

```
server {
        listen 443;
        server_name funkytown;
        ssl_certificate           /etc/nginx/cert.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key       /etc/nginx/cert.key;
        ssl on;
        location / {
                proxy_pass https:// 174.47.225.118/;
                #proxy_pass https:// www.google.com;
        }
        location = /favicon.ico {
                return 204;
                access_log     off;
                log_not_found  off;
}
}
```

The nginx.conf is just the default for nginx version: nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu).  This is a brand new install of ubuntu 14 running in AWS.  I have no reason to this the server is weird in anyway.

If anybody can help me figure out why this simple proxy isn't working you'll be my hero!  Bonus points for anybody that can figure out why this site fails in lynx and wget but works in curl and openssl.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1):

In summary: I see multiple problems at the server side which might result in the problems you see. If you have access to the server try to fix them there.

First it looks like the SSL stack of your target host (174.47.225.118) is kind of broken:

- It will do a successful handshake when SSLv23 with openssl DEFAULT cipher set is used. This will result in RC4-MD5 (which is bad because of RC4) and TLSv1.
- If you use 'ALL' instead of 'DEFAULT' it will use DES-CBC3-SHA which is better.
- But if you use 'ALL:!DES-CBC3-SHA' it will fail. This is strange because this cipher set includes RC4-MD5 which was used successfully before.

Just from this it looks like a broken stack which might work in some situations but not in others. But there is more:

- When I try with curl with certificate validation disabled it works and gets the HTTP response.
- When I try with wget with certificate validation disabled it does an successful SSL handshake and wget sends the request, but then the server closes the connection after another SSL handshake without sending a response (at least it looks like this from a packet capture).

If I try to send the request with `s_client` it looks like the server does a renegotiation directly after the HTTP request was sent and sends its certificate again. I think this unexpected behavior will break some clients.

Comment: Sadly I have no access to the server.  The problem is there for sure and I'm simply trying to work around it.